# In swagger, is it possible import multiple yaml files in one single file?

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor, openapi

For the Client this one is inside of client.yaml

```
/clients:
    get:
      tags:
      - "Clients"
      description: "List Clients The list capability"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      parameters:
      - name: "tenantIdentifier"
        in: "query"
        required: true
        type: "array"
        items:
          type: "string"
          enum:
          - "default"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "successful operation"
        400:
          description: "Invalid status value"
      security:
      - basicAuth: []
    post:
      tags:
      - "Clients"
      summary: "Create client if address is enabled"
      description: ""
      operationId: "addClient"
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      parameters:
      - name: "tenantIdentifier"
        in: "query"
        description: ""
        required: true
        type: "array"
        items:
          type: "string"
          enum:
          - "default"
      - in: "body"
        name: "body"
        description: "Add what do you wnat to add "
        required: true
        schema:
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/definitions/ClientStructure1'
            - $ref: '#/definitions/ClientStructure2'
            - $ref: '#/definitions/ClientStructure3'
      responses:
        405:
          description: "Invalid input"
      security:
      - basicAuth: []
```

For the USER this is inside of user.yaml

```
  /users:
    get:
      tags:
      - "Users"
      summary: "Retrieve list of users"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      parameters:
      - name: "tenantIdentifier"
        in: "query"
        required: true
        type: "array"
        items:
          type: "string"
          enum:
          - "default"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "successful operation"
        400:
          description: "Invalid status value"
      security:
      - basicAuth: []
    post:
      tags:
      - "Users"
      summary: "Adds new application user."
      description: "Note: Password information is not required (or processed). Password details at present are auto-generated and then sent to the email account given (which is why it can take a few seconds to complete)."
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      parameters:
      - name: "tenantIdentifier"
        in: "query"
        description: ""
        required: true
        type: "array"
        items:
          type: "string"
          enum:
          - "default"
      - in: "body"
        name: "body"
        description: "Mandatory Fields: username, firstname, lastname, email, officeId, roles, sendPasswordToEmail"
        required: true
        schema:
           $ref: "#/definitions/StructureForCreateUSer"          
      responses:
        400:
          description: ""
        404:
          description: ""
      security:
      - basicAuth: []
```

Comment: I'm afraid your question is unclear. Can you add examples of multiple YAML files, and the resulting file you are expecting to get? The more details the better.

Comment: Thanks for naswer.For example I have 2 tags one of them user and another  is client : "https://localhost:8443/fineract-provider/api/v1/users?tenantIdentifier=default" and "https://localhost:8443/fineract-provider/api/v1/client?tenantIdentifier=default" . For client the operations Put,Get,Delete and Post I wrote in client.yaml and for user in user.yaml.Now I want to connect them in swagger editor. Is it possible?

Comment: Please post sample contents of client.yaml and user.yaml.

Comment: I added. They are in different file. Is it possible to import like $ref: client.yaml and $ref: user.yaml  both of them ?

Comment: I found it.It is working.

Comment: I suggest to use indipendent Yaml parser that link multiple yaml into one with '$include' tag. In this way you create a command like `npm run build-doc` using yamlinc as main command https://github.com/javanile/yamlinc

Answer (score 15):

You can't `$ref` whole paths, but you can `$ref` the contents of individual paths. In your example, you can use:

```yaml
paths:
  /clients:
    $ref: clients.yaml#/~1clients
  /users:
    $ref: users.yaml#/~1users
```

`clients.yaml#/~1clients` means we take the `clients.yaml` file, then read the contents of the `/clients` node in that file and substitute the `$ref` with that contents. `~1clients` is `/clients` with `/` escaped as `~1` according to JSON Pointer rules.

To simplify the references, you can remove the `/clients:` and `/users:` nodes from your `clients.yaml` and `users.yaml` files

```yaml
# clients.yaml
get:
  description: "List Clients The list capability"
  ...
post:
  summary: "Create client if address is enabled"
  ...
```

and then use

```yaml
paths:
  /clients:
    $ref: clients.yaml
  /users:
    $ref: users.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenAPI 3 allows the use of the $ref keyword:

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/

Comment: This is wrong. 1) The `#/definitions/...` syntax is used to refer to data models in the _same file_. 2) `allOf` is only used in data models (schemas) and not in operation definitions.

Comment: Removed the example. The link to the documentation should be enough to point the user in the right direction.